# Translating list with checkboxes, to a combo of dropdowns

Tags: lists, dropdown

I have this list with checkboxes:
[image]

My Product Manager wants to consolidate the information, because:

1. It's overwhelming.
2. It takes up a lot of space, and we may not have all that space, where this feature is going.
3. No one will ever need all options. Most users will need only few.

I put together this dropdown combo, as an alternative. Is this the best UX? What are other options?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try consolidating the ethnicity and percentage into a single element, which makes adding and removing easier.

You would start with a single row. Once selected, if the user needs to add another ethnicity to their profile, only then would they add another row with the  <kbd>+</kbd>  button.

[image]

This way the choice of ethnicity and percentage is a single element, and you change both the ethnicity selection and amount close to each other, and just add or remove as needed.

This element is sometimes known as a **form stack**.

Comment: Thank you. There are few little problems with this suggestion. You are basically suggesting, I take entries from my one Ethnicity dropdown, and make them into multiple individual, persistent drop-downs. There are 12 entries, in the Ethnicity dropdown. So:

1) 12 drop-downs take up the same amount of room as my Option #1, which was the list. 

2) Instead of selecting multiple choices, in my one multi-select dropdown menu, user now has to click into 12 drop-downs, and select.

Comment: I’m suggesting you only start with a single drop down, nd only add a row If there is another ethnicity

Comment: You would never see more rows than you need to complete the ethnic profile. I agree that showing 12 dropdowns at once would an awful experience

Comment: @Yelena I've updated the answer for a little more clarity on my part.

Comment: Ah I see now! User clicks "+" if there are more entries/ethnicities needed! Thank you very much for explaining. Yes, that works. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem stems from choosing the wrong control for this information - assuming that you can't be both "1-25%" and "26-50%" at the same time, you need only a single selection within each row of checkboxes. Meaning that you need a list of radio buttons, along with an option to cancel this row altogether. You replaced this with a dropdown, but I think that with this specific data the next logical step is to use a slider, because your values are on a numerical scale.

So, to add to Mike's suggestion to dynamically build the form, I would approach it like this:

[image]